# Which 了 is this in 虽然那件衬衫很好看，但是太贵了！

Tags: grammar

Although that shirt looks nice, it's too expensive!

I've noticed that based on feel, I will say 太貴了, but I don't actually know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, 了 is used to strengthen/emphasize/intensify the adjective before it. It falls in the pattern of:

- 太 [adjective] 了
- 可 [adjective] 了
- [adjective] 极了
- [adjective] 死了

太貴了 - too expansive; too costly.

[Chinese le grammar summary (了)](https://www.chineseboost.com/grammar/le-grammar-summary/)

Answer (score 0):

太 is just an adverb, equivalent to very, so in English. Chinese usually add adverb to enhance the tone.
For example, 你真好看，这太棒了, we're not going to say, 你好看，这棒了。